# R - Appending data to a data.frame

Tags: r

I have a data set which looks like this:

```
job_id start_hour duration
   1     14        3
   2     8         2
```

Job_id: the id of the job

start_hour: the hour at which the job starts

duration: the number of hours required for the job

I would like to turn it into a table where each line represents an hour for the job:

```
job_id hour
   1   14
   1   15
   1   16
   2   8
   2   9
```

So I would have for each job, as much lines as the job requires hours to be done.

Is there an elegant way to do this in R?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is also possible with simple base functions. First, an input data.frame

```
#sample data
dd<-data.frame(
    job_id = 1:2, 
    start_hour = c(14, 8), 
    duration = c(3, 2)
)
```

Now we use `Map` to walk through each row and expand it to the right size. Then we combine all the newly expanded rows into one data.frame with `do.call(rbind,...)`

```
#transformation
do.call(rbind,Map(function(id,start,dur) {
    data.frame(
        job_id=rep(id, dur), 
        hour=seq(from=start, by=1, length.out=dur))
}, dd$job_id, dd$start_hour, dd$duration))
```

which gives us

```
  job_id hour
1      1   14
2      1   15
3      1   16
4      2    8
5      2    9
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is using the package `plyr` (where `d` is your original data frame)

```
ddply(d, .(job_id),
    function(d) data.frame(job_id = d$job_id, 
        hour = d$start_hour:(d$start_hour + d$duration -1)))
```